# GridSearchCV tuning hyperparameter error: The first argument to `Layer.call` must always be passed

Tags: python, deep-learning, gridsearchcv

I am new to deep learning, I am using GridSearchCV to tune the hyperparameters including epoch number and batch size, first I built the model:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
import numpy
    
# Build the model
def build_model(in_shape):
  model = Sequential()

  # Convolution 1
  model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(7,7), activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1), input_shape=in_shape))
  model.add(Dropout(0.2))

  # Convolution 2
  model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(5,5), activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)))
  model.add(Dropout(0.3))

  # Convolution 3
  model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
  model.add(Dropout(0.5))

  # Convolution 4
  model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3,3), activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3)))

  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(384, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)))
  model.add(Dropout(0.2))

  model.add(Dense(600, activation='softmax'))

  # Compile model
  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam')
  
  return model

in_shape = (1025, 22, 1)
model = build_model(in_shape=in_shape)
```

Then I used GridSearchCV to tune number of epochs and batch_size.

```
# Function to create model, required for KerasClassifier
# fix random seed for reproducibility



seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)
    
# create model
model_tune = KerasClassifier(build_fn=build_model(in_shape), verbose=0)
# define the grid search parameters
batch_size = [10, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100]
epochs = [10, 50, 100]
param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model_tune, param_grid=param_grid)
grid_result = grid.fit(x_val, y_val)
# summarize results
print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
    print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))
```

`x_val.shape`: (1025, 22, 1)
`y_val.shape`: (3360, 600);
Class of `x_val` and `y_val`: `numpy.ndarray`

Then I ran the GridSearch, it returned this error:

ValueError: The first argument to `Layer.call` must always be passed.
The error arised from this line of code: `grid_result = grid.fit(x_val, y_val)`
What does this error mean and how can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using PyTorch anywhere in the code? It seems to be `scikit-learn` and `keras`. Please remove the `pytorch` tag to avoid confusion

Comment: yes I have removed, do you have any ideas on the solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because the build_fn is not callable. The build_fn argument to KerasClassifier should be callable.
So, replacing this

```
model_tune = KerasClassifier(build_fn=build_model(in_shape), verbose=0)
```

with this will help.

```
model_tune = KerasClassifier(build_fn=lambda:build_model(in_shape), verbose=0)
```